# Real Time Update High charts from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I have two php files data.php and gaschart.php , data.php pull data from sql and gaschart.php draws the high chart. I want to make this realtime, meaning updating the graph every second, Database is also updating every second. Anyone please help me with this code. can anyone please show me how to do it for my code here..??

This is the **data.php**

```
  <?php
       $con = mysql_connect("localhost","shsas","");

    if (!$con) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
               }

    mysql_select_db("shsas", $con);

   $sth = mysql_query("SELECT Gaslevel FROM gas");
   $rows = array();
   $rows['name'] = 'Gaslevel';
   while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
   $rows['data'][] = $r['Gaslevel'];
   }

  $result = array();
  array_push($result,$rows);

  print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

  mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

This is the **gaschart.php**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
     var chart;
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25,
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Gas Level Detection',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'EventID'
                },

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Level of gas'
                },

            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: json
               });
             });

         });

       });
    </script>
```

Comment: Updating database every second?? Want to update charts using traditional HTTP requests? Sounds horrible idea to me.

Comment: This is a project there is a sensor it reads values every second and store it in a data base actually time period can be different may be 5 seconds or so, so the chart also needs to be populating accordingly.

Comment: Use Sockets or Streams. You want a chart which is somewhat like Sensex which is constantly updating. I would suggest, please don't use traditional HTTP requests.

Comment: I think this is the way to do it but i cannot integrate this with my code. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576769/grabbing-data-from-mysql-using-php-realtime#)

Comment: yes that's what i want to know, the problem is where to call the sockets, can you please tell me where should i call the function by a simple example ??

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you to try using Sockets.

You can check [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Although it is developed for chatting. I am sure, you can use it for your use-case.

Also, check [elephant.io](http://elephant.io/). It is more generic. A light and easy to use library that aims to bring some real-time functionality. You can also try this for your project. Internally, it uses socket.io

Comment: Thanks dude.. i'll check it

Comment: can you please show me with my code how to perform it. it's not working for me.